# Function that takes a 2d list and finds the max of the columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion

I'm trying to write a function that takes a 2d list, finds the part of the list that has the highest value in its column, and returns that part of the list including the row and the column.

This is a homework problem that simulates Scrabble. Essentially, you give the function a list of characters and it returns a list of the best word you could make out of characters based on that word's value and the value itself.

There's some global variables in this problem: scrabbleScores (a list of that characters and their values) and Dictionary (all the words you could possibly make).

For example, if you gave it the list, ['a', 's', 'm', 't', 'p'], it would first call another function that returns all of the words you could make from that list and their values, then it would use that list and return a list with the best word and its value.

So, I already have a function that I've been working on, but whenever I run it my IDE gives me a "int object is not subscriptable" error:

```
scrabbleScores = \
   [ ['a', 1], ['m', 3], ['p', 3], ['s', 1], ['t', 1] ]

Dictionary = ['a', 'am', 'at', 'apple', 'bat', 'bar', 'babble', 'can', 'foo',
              'spam', 'spammy', 'zzyzva']
#implementation missing because it works just fine, so just ignore this function
def letterScore(letter, scoreList):
    ''' letter = string; scoreList = list in the form of [character, value]
        returns the value associated with letter in scoreList '''
#implementation missing because it works just fine, so just ignore this function
def wordScore(S, scoreList):
    ''' S = string; scoreList = list in the form of [character, value]
        returns the sum of the values for each character in S '''

def scoreList(Rack):
    ''' Rack = list of lower-case characters
    returns a list of all of the words in the global Dictionary that can be made
    from those letters and the score for each word '''
    def scoreListHelper(Rack, Dictionary):
        if Dictionary == []:
            return []
        elif all(c in Rack for c in Dictionary[0]):
            return [[Dictionary[0], wordScore(Dictionary[0], scrabbleScores)]] + 
            scoreListHelper(Rack, Dictionary[1:])
        else:
            return scoreListHelper(Rack, Dictionary[1:])
    return scoreListHelper(Rack, Dictionary)

#this is the function that's having issues
def bestWord(Rack):
    ''' Rack = list of lower-case characters
    returns a list of the highest possible scoring word from Rack and the score 
    of the word '''
    def bestWordHelper(L):
        if L == []:
            return []
        elif len(L) == 1:
            return [L[0], L[0][0]]
        else:
            if L[1][1] > L[0][1]:
                return bestWordHelper(L[1:])
            else:
                return bestWordHelper(bestWordHelper(L[0:1]) + 
                bestWordHelper(L[1]))

    return bestWordHelper(scoreList(Rack))

print(bestWord(['a', 's', 'm', 't', 'p']))
```

scoreList() returns '[['a', 1], ['am', 4], ['at', 2], ['spam', 8]]' and bestWord() should return '['spam', 8]', but again, it keeps giving me that error.

If y'all can give me some pointers, that would be much appreciated. Lastly, if you provide a solution, it should work recursively/without loops. For whatever reason we're not allowed to use loops for this assignment.
P.S. I know my 'scoreList()' function has a loop but I'm going to change it later to see if I can make work just using recursion. For now, just ignore my hypocrisy. :P

Comment: error shows you which line makes problem so use `print()` to see values in variables in this line. it seems you have single integer value in variable but you treat it as list - Run ie. `5[1]` and you get the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is complicated but I found few mistakes which resolved problem with error.

`bestWordHelper()` needs 2D list but problem is `[]` in some places and `+` between list's elements so sometimes it creates 1D list instead of 2D list and then it can't get second dimention when you use `L[0][1]` - and finally you get `integer[0]` instead of `list[0]` so you get your error message `"int object is not subscriptable"`

---

First: you forgot `[1]` in

```
 return [L[0][1], L[0][0]]
```

---

As I said `bestWordHelper()` needs 2D list but in line

```
 return bestWordHelper(bestWordHelper(L[0:1]) + bestWordHelper(L[1]))
```

you have `L[1]` which is 1D list. There should be rather `L[1:]`

Other problem in the same line is `+` which concatenate to 1D lists and create 1D list but it has to create 2D list

```
 return bestWordHelper( [bestWordHelper(L[0:1]), bestWordHelper(L[1L])] )
```

---

Finally code (with some `print()` for debugging information)

I also converted list `scrabbleScores` to dictionary because it is more useful in this code. With dictionary it is much easier to get `letterScore` and `wordScore`

```
scrabbleScores = [['a', 1], ['m', 3], ['p', 3], ['s', 1], ['t', 1]]

scrabbleScores = dict(scrabbleScores)
print(scrabbleScores)
#scrabbleScores = {'a': 1, 'm': 3, 'p': 3, 's': 1, 't': 1}

Dictionary = ['a', 'am', 'at', 'apple', 'bat', 'bar', 'babble', 'can', 'foo',
              'spam', 'spammy', 'zzyzva']

#implementation missing because it works just fine, so just ignore this function
def letterScore(letter, scoreList):
    ''' letter = string; scoreList = list in the form of [character, value]
        returns the value associated with letter in scoreList '''
    return scoreList[letter]

#implementation missing because it works just fine, so just ignore this function
def wordScore(S, scoreList):
    ''' S = string; scoreList = list in the form of [character, value]
        returns the sum of the values for each character in S '''
    return sum(scoreList[letter] for letter in S)

def scoreList(Rack):
    ''' Rack = list of lower-case characters
    returns a list of all of the words in the global Dictionary that can be made
    from those letters and the score for each word '''
    def scoreListHelper(Rack, Dictionary):
        if Dictionary == []:
            return []
        elif all(c in Rack for c in Dictionary[0]):
            return [[Dictionary[0], wordScore(Dictionary[0], scrabbleScores)]] + scoreListHelper(Rack, Dictionary[1:])
        else:
            return scoreListHelper(Rack, Dictionary[1:])
    return scoreListHelper(Rack, Dictionary)

#this is the function that's having issues
def bestWord(Rack):
    ''' Rack = list of lower-case characters
    returns a list of the highest possible scoring word from Rack and the score 
    of the word '''
    def bestWordHelper(L):
        print('input:', L)
        if not L:
            print('empty')
            return []
        elif len(L) == 1:
            print('one:', L, '->', [L[0][1], L[0][0]])
            return [L[0][1], L[0][0]]
        else:
            print('many:', L)
            if L[1][1] > L[0][1]:
                return bestWordHelper(L[1:])
            else:
                return bestWordHelper([bestWordHelper(L[0:1]), bestWordHelper(L[1:])])

    result = scoreList(Rack)
    print('result:', result)
    return bestWordHelper(result)

print(bestWord(['a', 's', 'm', 't', 'p']))
```

Comment: Ok that seemed to have worked perfectly. Thank you so much!